# Docker COPY does not copy certain files in application

Tags: angularjs, docker

I have an Angular application with the following Dockerfile

```
FROM node:8
ENV APP_HOME /app
RUN mkdir -pv $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
ENV NODE_ENV production
ENV NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL warn
ENV CUSTOM_REGISTRY https://registry.npmjs.org/
RUN npm config set strict-ssl false
RUN npm config set registry $CUSTOM_REGISTRY
COPY . $APP_HOME
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
RUN npm install
```

As you can see, in the copy command, we copy the current directory to the working directory of the container, however, after I SSH into the container to check if all the files were copied, I see that files which have two `.` in them are not copied.

Some examples are -

```
.angular-cli.json
.travis.yml
```

How can I move these files over to the container, the `.angular-cli.json` is specially critical for me to make the application run.

Comment: Can you show the command you run inside the container to check, and also show the contents of any `.dockerignore` file you have.